# Count Function for Top Level of Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to write a function that counts the number of entries in the highest level of the pivot table (ie. the A, B, C, and D). What Excel function can I write that would yield a result of 4 for this pivot table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This key in working with pivot table fields (`PivotFields`) is that there are several conditions to check to make sure you're dealing with the one(s) you want. In your case, you want to make sure you're looking at fields that are `Rows` and are in the first position (top level).

I have a whole set of public pivot table functions that exposes these types of checks to make it easy on me. I'm using two of them to show you a solution to your question.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TopLevelRows() As Long
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim thisPT As PivotTable
    Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set thisPT = thisWS.PivotTables(1)

    Dim numberOfTopLevelRows As Long
    numberOfTopLevelRows = 0

    Dim pField As PivotField
    For Each pField In thisPT.PivotFields
        If PivotFieldIsRow(thisPT, pField.Name) And _
          (PivotFieldPosition(thisPT, pField.Name) = 1) Then
            '--- there will only be one of these, so iterate on the items
            Dim pItem As PivotItem
            '--- we can't assume that the .Count equals the number of
            '    items because there may be a "(blank)" entry
            'Debug.Print "count = " & pField.PivotItems.count
            For Each pItem In pField.PivotItems
                If pItem.Caption <> "(blank)" Then
                    numberOfTopLevelRows = numberOfTopLevelRows + 1
                End If
            Next pItem
        End If
    Next pField

    Debug.Print "there are " & numberOfTopLevelRows & " top level rows in the pivot table"
    TopLevelRows = numberOfTopLevelRows 'return value
End Function

Private Function PivotFieldIsRow(ByRef pTable As PivotTable, _
                                 ByVal ptFieldName As String) As Boolean
    Dim field As PivotField
    PivotFieldIsRow = False
    For Each field In pTable.RowFields
        If field.Name = ptFieldName Then
            PivotFieldIsRow = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next field
End Function

Private Function PivotFieldPosition(ByRef pTable As PivotTable, _
                                    ByVal ptFieldName As String) As Long
    Dim field As PivotField
    PivotFieldPosition = 0
    For Each field In pTable.PivotFields
        If field.Name = ptFieldName Then
            If TypeName(field.position) = "Error" Then
                '--- we'll get an error if the field is not included as a
                '    row or column. this isn't a problem, but there's no
                '    real position in this case, so return 0
            Else
                PivotFieldPosition = field.position
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next field
End Function
```

Now in cell A30 write the formula `=TopLevelRows()` and you should get your result.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT! Please excuse my ignorance, but how would I make use of this function to generate a count value of 4 in a cell in my Excel workbook? Thanks again!

Comment: thanks @PeterT for the additional detail; however, I think I am failing to ask my question properly. Let me try again, if I wanted to write a formula in say cell, A30, what function would I need to write to generate the result of 4 in that cell? Hopefully that clarifies my question a bit!

Comment: As far as I know, there is not an existing Excel function that will give you the result you're looking for. I've modified the code slightly to turn the counting `Sub` into a `Function` (which makes it a UDF - User Defined Function). Save your spreadsheet as a Macro-Enabled spreadsheet and this will work.

Comment: I appreciate the additional info, @PeterT. I tried adding this to the spreadsheet and saved the workbook as macro-enabled, but the `=TopLevelRows()` formula results in a #NAME? error when entered into cell A30. Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There was one error in my code. For the `TopLevelRows` routine, it should end with `End Function` instead of `End Sub`. If you change that, it should work (it worked fine for me).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts;however, I was unable to get this approach to work. I figured out a solution by doing a running total on the highest level of the pivot table and simply putting a max of that column in cell A30. The result in A30 changes as selections are made with slicers by the end user. Thank you for your help! I will give you the best answer award as your approach guided me towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the second field out of the PivotTable entirely, drag the first field from the rows area the Values area, and you will automatically get a COUNT of the number of fields if it is a text field. (Otherwise, change the aggregation from SUM to COUNT)

[image]

Comment: Agreed, this approach does result in the desired count; however, I should have phrased my question better as this hierarchical pivot table is part of a dashboard and the highest level count is needed in a separate cell to be readily displayed to the end user. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Great: Use GETPIVOTDATA in combination with the above approach, and connect your two PivotTabes together with a Slicer so that the fields are in sync should someone filter the main 'display' PivotTable.